# After upgrading to 18.04 from 16.04, I am unable to use nautilus or use the terminal or listen to any audio and my internet speed has reduced

Tags: 16.04, sound, 18.04, nautilus

So I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 and I have been trying to use it. But nothing is working. I have looked up various answers on askubuntu and I have been unable to fix any of the symptoms.
The terminal refuses to open, but I have been able to use xterm from which I have been able to open the file explorer using nautilus command. However, I cannot open it via clicking on the icon. For the audio, I have tried using the guide mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) by installing  Pavucontrol but that hasn't worked either. For the terminal, I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040566/cant-open-terminal-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-upgrade-from-17-10)  but my system languages seem okay. Plus I have been trying to watch videos and even posting this question proved to be horribly slow, and this was not an issue ever before.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help out here.

Edit : I tried changing the language to UK and making everything UK in the Languages section but that has not helped either.

Comment: There's probably a way to repair it, but it might be faster and less painful to just reinstall.

Comment: I have no idea how to go about that. I have a dual booted HP system and have data I cannot afford to lose.

Comment: See [How to reinstall Ubuntu in the easiest way?](https://askubuntu.com/q/446102/301745) and make sure to make a backup before you start.

Comment: @wjandrea, is there no way out of this without a hard reset?

Comment: If there is, I don't know what it is. So to me, the more obvious solution is just to reinstall.

Comment: BTW, a [hard reset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_reset) is something different. But on that note, have you already tried restarting the machine?

Comment: I tried everything and have been able to make the audio work. The terminal isn't working still or the file explorer but I have been able to open the file explorer by typing 'nautilus' in the xterm

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"?

Comment: I tried a lot of sources which I will list down and rebooted my pc. Somehow it managed to work for ten minutes

Comment: Apologies for the delay but I had reset everything back to normal in the BIOS and somehow that made things work... for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue, the surefix is to downgrade to 16.04, or in case of specific programs, replace them with something else as I used Nemo instead of Nautilus and Terminator in place of gnome-terminal. There is no fix for the audio issue that seemed to work, so you might want to back up all your data and just re-install all the OS.
Following the regular procedure of installation did the trick for me.