# After updating to ubuntu 18.04, I have had issues with sound in certain apps

Tags: gnome, sound, 18.04, spotify

The Alarm Clock applet does run however the alarm does not ring anymore.
[As I  had mentioned earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067808/after-upgrading-to-18-04-from-16-04-i-am-unable-to-use-nautilus-or-use-the-term), I had issues with sound on my laptop, Here's a screenshot of my sound [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMDNN.png) but the thing is that sound does work for some applications, namely Chrome and VLC but it doesn't work for Spotify or any of my clock based apps.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
When I try to run gnome-clocks from the terminal, it does open but it displays this message

> (gnome-clocks:30888): WARNING **: 12:45:39.431: AT-SPI: Could not
>   obtain desktop path or name
>
> ** (gnome-clocks:30888): WARNING **: 12:45:39.435: atk-bridge: GetRegisteredEvents returned message with unknown signature
>
> ** (gnome-clocks:30888): WARNING **: 12:45:39.435: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature
>
> ** (gnome-clocks:30888): WARNING **: 12:45:39.435: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature
>
> (gnome-clocks:30888): org.gnome.Clocks-WARNING **: 12:45:39.566:
>   geocoding.vala:44: Failed to connect to GeoClue2 service:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Geolocation
>   disabled for UID 1 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all boiled down to the fact that my laptop's hard drive was dying back then. It was slowly happening but it caused files to get corrupted and I lost tonnes of data. If anyone browses this question in the future, please please just back up your data immediately and get your hard disk replaced pronto.

For more information,see my profile and these questions:

[A permanent fix that I can personally vouch for. Just ensure you have a warranty on your PC as I did.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108310/i-encountered-the-print-req-error-while-trying-to-open-ubuntu-16-04-on-my-dual-b)

[A temporary fix as you are bound to encounter the same error when you restart your computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox)

I can't find the source anymore but if I do, I will link it.

These issues boil down to laptop manufacturer's using older parts in newer laptops.
My laptop is an HP Pavilion 15 inch model, and it was manufactured in 2016. However, the hard disk itself was manufactured much earlier. HDDs are known to be very delicate things and even though I took utmost care of my laptop, the hard disk just began dying. Do not despair and act immediately. The longer you delay it, the more the data you are bound to lose. In the final days of my laptop, I had to switch to Windows and use a tool to access my Ubuntu partition as the Ubuntu had stopped booting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my `Spotify`, I tried the following and it fixed.

Go to the

> `settings`->`Sound`->`Application`

`Spotify` was `off` I just `on` it and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Hi mate, it wasn't as simple as that. I have highlighted what worked for me in my answer.