# Cannot open terminal in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I have a recent installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1.

When I open a terminal, a tab shows in the taskbar for a few sencods but then it fades away. The same with Files

I've seen other users suggest to change the language but did not work for me.

Not much I can add for now

Comment: can you switch to something like tty2?

Comment: I can switch to tty2

Comment: In my case, the answer was here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040568/620474

Answer (score 4):

I just moved the .gnome folder from tty2. Pressed
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to log in into tty2
then used

```
mv .gnome .gnome.backup
```

This is `/home/myuser/`

And voila! it's working again

Comment: There is no hidden .gnome folder!