# sudo apt-get update subprocess returned an error code

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I **am running Ubuntu 18.04** and I noticed that at the top-left corner of the screen, suddenly [this icon had appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUthS.jpg). I thought that it was due to a brief disconnection, so I didn't worry that much.

Now, whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` the process stops with this error:

```
Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease                      
Hit:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
Traceback (most recent call last):                 
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

---

The only "wicked" thing I recall doing before seeing such icon is entering `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 0` to prioritize this newer version of Python.

Since by the error I can see that some python import fails, I thought I'd make it clear.
So far I've tried:

- sudo apt-get clean
- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- sudo apt-get autoremove
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt-get install apt_pkg --> `E: Unable to locate package apt_pkg`
- sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python && sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3

--> output error changed to

```
(...)
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

---

**Moreover**: I can't access my terminal anymore. The only unconvenient way I find is to right-click anywhere and then select "Open terminal". For this, I've tried

- [changing the language settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040566/cant-open-terminal-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-upgrade-from-17-10), even if they never got
  corrupted.
- launching the terminal from the 'Apps', which results in a notification saying `failed to execute child process gnome-terminal:
  no such file or directory`
- launching it via 'right click' and entering `$ gnome-terminal` results in `bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3: bad
  interpreter: No such file or directory`

Hope that solving one solves the other..

Comment: could you be more specific on how to do so? would it break some configs that i have?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3-apt (not sudo apt-get install apt_pkg)

Comment: I have got exactly the same problem and I am exactly at the stage in which @davidem. was on Sep 23 '19 at 17:36.
is the re-installation of Ubuntu really the only solution?

Comment: @Alberto for me it was, the solutions I was able to find had root problems that didn't match with mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu: no matter how many solutions I found, the causing problems were too diverse, even if all resembled the fact of somehow messing with the Python default version.

I guess Python truly **is** something that you should be extra-careful when handling with Ubuntu. Lesson learned the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Use update-alternatives to put the default python version back to what it was. I am also running Ubuntu 18.04 my python version is 2.7.15

`$ python --version`
`Python 2.7.15+`

Then I would recommend looking into setting up virtual python environments using `venv` (venv in python3 and virtualenv for python2) for testing or running programs that require python 3.

First, make sure you have pip installed by running `sudo apt install python3-pip` or ensure that it is up to date by running `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip`.

Then install venv by running `python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv`

I hate to link you to an outside webpage but there are clear instructions on doing this on the python.org website. You can find a link to the site at [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: I'll tell you the truth, i don't actually need to run programs that require python3. I was just testing a compatibility, but for some reason python3 was an older version, so i added that alternative in order to prioritize the 3.7 version. that's all

Comment: Ahhh yes. You have to be careful when using update-alternatives because so much of the operating system relies on the default version of python. Something I had to learn the hard way.

Comment: well, had i know this before i'd have kept myself at distance. what can you suggest me? i've already removed all the update-alternatives but the only result is the output error changing. i've edited the question

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? Please add that in the question as well

Comment: forgot to say, 18.04, edited

Comment: I updated my answer. The default python version should be 2.7.15. use ``update-alternatives --config`` to put it back. and then check to make sure it is correct by running ``python --version``

Comment: python --version does give me the expected output, but still the same errors occurr. i have edited the question to include more errors when launching the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Hm, try the "windows-way"

```
sudo apt install --reinstall  python3-commandnotfound  command-not-found
```